# Up to several variables can be used for tuples?

Tags: c#, tuple-struct

I have heard that up to 7 variables can be used, but I have requested more. I want to know the maximum number of variables that can be used.

Comment: You can read more about Console.WriteLine() and Console.ReadKey() to find your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tuples are unlimited, pay attention to this example:

```
var t1 = ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g","h","i");
        Console.WriteLine(t1);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

and now we can say that tuples are unlimited because they don't only take 7 varibles but have more capacity

Answer (score 8):

It is effectively unlimited. The documentation for a `Tuple` with more than seven properties is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.tuple-8?view=net-6.0). The eighth property can  itself be a `Tuple`. The eighth property of that can also be a `Tuple` and so on until the system runs out of space. As an example, this code:

```cs
var data =
    new Tuple<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, Tuple<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, Tuple<int, int>>>(
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
        new Tuple<int, int, int, int, int, int, int, Tuple<int, int>>(
            1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
            Tuple.Create(1, 2)));

Console.WriteLine(data.ToString());
```

produces the following output:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2)
```

It's worth noting that this code:

```cs
var data = Tuple.Create(
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
    Tuple.Create(
        1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
        Tuple.Create(1, 2)));

Console.WriteLine(data.ToString());
```

produces this slightly different output:

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, (1, 2)))
```

The documentation does say this:

> To create an n-tuple with nine or more components, you must call the Tuple<T1,T2,T3,T4,T5,T6,T7,TRest> constructor. The static factory methods of the Tuple class do not support the creation of Tuple objects with more than eight components.

Answer (score -1):

```
var date = =Tuple.Create(
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,
tuple.creat(
1,2,3,4,5,6,7
tuple.create(1,2)));
console.writeline(data.topstring());
```

Comment: I suggest that you take a look at the second half of my answer. It addresses the fact that this does not produce the same result using the `Tuple` constructor. The documentation that I linked to even explicitly states that you must use the constructor for nine or more elements and I quoted that passage. This answer is wrong.

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.